# How to update a single item in a list from the template in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am looking for the best way to make an updateable list from model objects in Django.

Let's say that I have a models.py:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and I have a views.py that shows the objects from that model:

```
def my_view(request):
    person_list = Person.objects.all()
    ctx= {'person_list': person_list}
    return render(request, 'my_app/my_view.html', ctx)
```

Then I have a template, my_view.html:

```
...

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>bar</th>
    <th>foo</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in person_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.bar}}</td>
      <td>{{item.foo}}</td>
      <td style="width: 5%;"><button type="submit" name="button">Change</button></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
...
```

So, I would like to add a form and make one of those fields changeable from within this template.

I would like users to be able to change item.foo and then click the change button and it sends the update to the model.

I tried making it a form, and using forms.py to create a form where users can put an input, and then submit the form, and that looked like this, my_view.html:

```
...
...

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>bar</th>
    <th>foo</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in person_list %}
  <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.bar}}</td>
      <td>{{item.foo}}</td>
      <td>{{form.foo}}</td>
      <td style="width: 5%;"><button type="submit" name="button">Change</button></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
...
...
```

And that was not working, because I couldn't figure out where to send the PK for that particular item in the Model.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `class-based views` very easily

Say this is your `models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    alpha = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    beta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gama = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    delta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Your `views.py` should be like this

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['beta'] # Include the fields you want to update form your template
```

As a reference, this will be your `CreateView` in `views.py` file

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'myapp/myapp_form.html'
    fields = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gama', 'delta']
```

This will be your `urls.py`

```
from .views import MyModelUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('app/<int:pk>/update/', MyModelUpdateView.as_view(), name='model-update'),
    ....
]
```

The default template for `UpdateView` is the one used for `CreateView`, `myapp_form.html` in this case. This will be your basic form template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am getting an error doing this, it says that UpdateView must be called with an object PK or a slug. But I want to view them all on the same page, and choose which ones to update on that same page. Is this possible?

Comment: I have added urls.py file. See if that helps you in re-directing.

Comment: Isn't this just going to take me to the update page? I want to update the items all from the same page.

Comment: If you want to update all the items from the same page then your view page will have the following line of code. `fields = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gama', 'delta']`